# Questions about combustion and isotopic abundance

Tags: combustion, stoichiometry, isotope

1. the combustion of 0.214g of sulfur provided exactly 0.428g of sulfur dioxide. After a second try, 0.782g of SO2 was obtained. What mass of sulfur was used?
2. The combustion of lithium forms lithium oxide. Combustion involving a 1.451g sample of oxygen results in obtaining 2.710g of Li2O. What mass of lithium was involved in this reaction?
3. Natural argon has three isotopes: Ar-36 (35.967u), Ar-38 (37.962u), and Ar-40 (39.962u). if the isotopic abundance of Ar-36 is 0.006%, find the isotopic abundance of the other two

After pulling my hair out:

1. I still have no idea how to do this question.
2. I balanced the equation $4Li + O_{2} -> 2Li_{2}O$ then found the moles of both oxygen and lithium oxide, which was 0.090688 mols and 0.090333 mols. Used the smaller number of moles, set up the ratios $\frac{4Li}{2Li_{2}O} = \frac{x}{0.090333mols}$
   x = 0.1807 mols, which equals to 1.2647g of Li
   Is this correct?
3. 35.967(0.00006) + 37.962(x) + 39.962(1-x) = 39.948
   0.00215802 + 37.962x + 39.962 - 39.962x = 39.948
   -2x = -0.01615802
   x = 0.00807901
   which mean Ar-38 is 0.8%, but the answer clearly says it is 0.588%

Comment: StackExchange should not do your homework for you, as that would be cheating.

Comment: @EricBrown First, this is not homework, they are just extra practices for the exam. Second, I don't know how to do this and there is nothing wrong with asking for help. There are more questions that goes in this format, I only asked one of each type of question so that I can apply the same method on the other questions. If I am intended to have people do my homework for me, I would have post all of them up.

Comment: Great.  I'm sure that you can understand why I made my previous statement, as there are two camps of folks who make answers on SE -- the very few who will answer homework questions, and those who will with some demonstration of effort by the person who asks the questions.

Comment: So 'demonstration of effort' means something like... showing what I got up to and let people correct my mistakes? If so, then sure I'll do that.

Comment: I checked a couple of references and they say the natural abundance of Ar-36 is 0.334%; Ar-38 is around 0.06%

Comment: Yes the answers at the back says  Ar-38 is 0.588% and Ar-40 is 99.406% But I have trouble getting these numbers.

Comment: I don't get those numbers either.  In the first question, write the equation for the burning (oxidation) of sulfur in oxygen and you'll see that 1 mole of sulfur generates 1 mole of sulfur dioxide.  Convert the masses of sulfur and sulfur dioxide to moles and you'll see that 0.007 moles of sulfur produced 0.007 moles of sulfur dioxide.  Then they did a second experiment and obtained 0.782 gm sulfur dioxide.  How many moles is that; so then how many moles of sulfur did they start with, and how many grams of sulfur is that?

Comment: whoops,  wouldn't 3 involve (1-.00006-x)?

Comment: BTW, in problem 3, because you are dealing with such widely different isotope natural abundances (e.g Ar-38 = 0.006% while Ar-40 = 99.6%) it is critical to use isotope masses out to at least 6 decimal places.  Otherwise your answer will be way off.

Comment: omg that's right I completely ignored the whole 0.00006 thing. Should be 1-0.00006-x. And I tried to keep a lot of decimal places too but the problem is that, usually during the exam, at the top of the page it would say something like 2 marks for keeping all significant figures. Sometimes there isn't any choice of how many decimal places I can keep. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $\frac{0.214g}{0.428g} = \frac {x}{0.782g}$
2. Your answer is ok, but on an exam you want to solve quickly.

   2.710g - 1.451g = ?

wasn't that easier?

3.

> 35.967(0.00006) + 37.962(x) + 39.962(1-x) = 39.948

This is slightly wrong.

0.00006, x, 0.99994-x